# Style BasedOn attribute failing at run-time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom button that derives from a Button control. This custom button's (GlyphButton) XAML page declares a style that specifies a control template as follows:

```
<Button x:Class="Foo.Presentation.Controls.GlyphButton">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                                Padding="1"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent">
                            <local:VectorImage x:Name="PART_VectorImage"
                                               Path="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GlyphButton}}, Path=Path}"
                                               Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GlyphButton}}, Path=Fill}"
                                               Stretch="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GlyphButton}}, Path=Stretch}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_VectorImage"
                                        Property="Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GlyphButton}}, Path=GlowColor, TargetNullValue='Black'}"
                                                          ShadowDepth="0"
                                                          BlurRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GlyphButton}}, Path=GlowRadius}"
                                                          Opacity="1.0" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

I use this control throughout my application. In one instance, I needed to add a context menu with custom styling to show the menu on a left mouse click so I came up with the following:

```
<controls:GlyphButton Height="24"
                      Width="24"
                      Path="{StaticResource HamburgerMenu4}"
                      Fill="{StaticResource BlueGradientBrush}">
     <controls:GlyphButton.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:GlyphButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:GlyphButton}}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                       <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                   <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                      <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                                         Value="True" />
                                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                             </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                   </EventTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
</controls:GlyphButton.Style>
```

At runtime, I get an exception stating that the Xaml parser cannot find a style named 'GlyphButton' when I include the BasedOn attribute shown above. I've discovered a current workaround by declaring the template inline as opposed to using a style that removed the need to base the lowest level style on anything.

```
<GlypButton>
    <GlyphButton.Template>
         <!-- Template goes here -->
    </GlyphButton.Template>
</GlypButton>
```

What am I missing here? Am I not following best practices by declaring the custom control's template through a style and if I am, why does this fail?

Comment: So your style template is sitting in a Button's resources with no way to reference it. Since that's what you're wanting to do, pull that style template out, give it a unique x:Key name, and throw it in a resource dictionary or somewhere your other button using it for BasedOn can actually hit as a resource, not a type. Your exception and workaround would be expected as-is.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Considering this button should never have a control template other than the one specified, can my workaround be considered an acceptable solution? That way, another dev will not have the responsibility of making sure any local style uses the BasedOn attribute just to maintain the control template.

Comment: Yea, I mean that depends on if you're going to want to use elements of either other places for anything but if this is all you're doing for the instance there's nothing really wrong with that.